# Is saying 'Good Noon' valid?

Tags: word-choice, greetings

How should I greet between 12pm and 2pm? Should I say 'Good Afternoon' or 'Good Noon'? Is Good Noon commonly used or not?

Comment: No, it's not common.  In fact, if I heard someone say that, and I had to transcribe it, I might even use an apostrophe (i.e., "Good 'noon") to denote a shortened form of "Good afternoon."  It's that uncommon, especially when compared to its counterpart.

Comment: 'Good noon' is unheard of. In AmE, 'good day and 'good afternoon' are recognized but not really used (obsolete even?), and 'good morning' and 'good night' are as everyday as every day.

Comment: Noon is technically a single fixed timepoint of 12:00:00.000 in the exact middle of the day. At 12:00:00.001 the time is now after noon. So the correct term should be good afternoon.

Comment: I wait for one second and say "good afternoon". How about that? Cheers!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, "Good Noon" is not commonly used. "Good Afternoon" is technically appropriate anytime after 12 noon. As an alternative, you could also say "Good Day".

Comment: 'Good day', or rather 'G'day' is, I believe, what Australians say, but it's hardly ever heard in the UK. 'Good afternoon' isn't all that common here either. As casual greetings, 'Hello' or 'Hi' are much more likely to be heard.

Comment: 'Good Day' is used in the UK, but more as a farewell or a dismissal, not as a welcome.

Comment: As an Aussie I can definitely confirm the "g'day" usage - and it doesn't matter what time of day or night it is ;-). "Good afternoon" does sound a bit formal, even stilted. It is usually abbreviated to simply "afternoon", and quite common in the business world, though not so common on informal occasions, where "hello", "hi" or "hey" (or variants thereof) are typically used between friends, as @Barrie says. In other (non-Aussie) parts of the world, "Good day" can seem old-fashioned and seems to have shifted from being a greeting to being a... shall we say, "cold shoulder departure" phrase.

Comment: @aaamos: In that case, G'day. Absolutely right about 'Good day' here. 'Then I wish you good day, sir', if heard at all, is unlikely to come at the end of a friendly encounter.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: Couldn't agree more. G'day right back atcha, mate, but I won't bid you "good day"....

Comment: Interestingly enough, "I bid you good day," or "I wish you good day" indeed sound terribly old-fashioned or cold-shouldered, and not too far removed from "good riddance!"  However, "have a good day" sounds normal and cordial, at least to my American ears, particularly at the end of a conversation.  As a greeting, "good day" sounds stiff, while "good afternoon" sounds relaxed.

Comment: I'd like to point out that in Australian schools, most younger pupils at the end of the day will chorus in unison 'Good after Mr/Mrs/Miss X'. At least in my experience.